# Video collapsing to to control bar on play

Tags: video.js

I'm using video.js and fitvids.js to show self hosted video on my site.  This was working great until the past 24 hours when I started to notice that the video would collapse down to the control bar when played.  This seemed to occur after I enabled Cloudflare for the first time.  I can still get full screen to work.

I have since disabled all cacheing programs, removed Cloudflare (and changed DNS settings back) and disabled fitvids.js but can't get 'normal behavior' unless I specify a certain height and width (Previously using 100% and auto was working great as per the code below).
Greatly appreciate your thoughts on how to fix this.

[Video page:](http://orenphotography.com/videos/) 
Current code:

```
[video mp4="http://url.mp4" video width="100%" video height="auto" video poster="http://url.png"]
```